# playframework 1.2.5, how to wire in something like the JPA plugin correctly(classloader issue)

Tags: playframework-1.x

I am trying to wire in a nosqlORM into play 1.2.5.  Currently, the issue occurs because the Class file instances are different each time after changes so the ORM layer scans all the Class files and creates a Class to MetaClass Map on startup but then later, the when a class is used, it is a different Class file each time.

I am looking at JPAPlugin.java in the playframework, but I don't see where they would rescan all the hibernate entities for their annotations(hibernate only scans for annotations on startup and never looks at them again so play must be doing something).

Does anyone know how this works?

WORSE yet, when I am in "play run" mode, it does not pick up the resource at all in the play files...(in debug mode, it DOES pick up the classes)....errr, more specifically ClassLoader.getResources("nosql/Persistence.class"); is only found in debug mode but not found in "play run" mode.  Interestingly though, it finds the instances that exist in other jars in the project.  I could move my model into a jar I guess for it to work, but that is kind of a pain as the edit and hit the web browser is a very nice feature.

thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Play calls JPAPlugin.onApplicationStart for every reload.
You can put a breakpoint on 'onApplicationStart' or change your log level to:
application.log=TRACE

And you'll see that hibernate is reloaded there.

Your module should complete reload 'nosqlORM' in 'onApplicationStart'.

Comment: yes, we figured it all out and now have an in-memory noSQL in place for playframework 1.2.x and 2.x with PlayOrm's inmemory noSQL and can switch easily now between that and cassandra.